# error: invalid conversion from 'DWORD {aka long unsigned int}' to 'PDWORD {aka long unsigned int*}' [-fpermissive]| how to fix?

Tags: c++, windows, syntax-error

I am pretty new to C++ and I am making a trainer(Plants vs Zombies)  I tried to make a trainer for that game before but it failed the memory writing didn't work so I tried another method but with this method it gives me a couple of errors:

> 54|error: invalid conversion from 'DWORD {aka long unsigned int}' to 'PDWORD
>       {aka long unsigned int*}' [-fpermissive]|
>
> 1780|error: initializing argument 2 of >'DWORDGetWindowThreadProcessId(HWND,PDWORD)'   [-fpermissive]|

I just don't get it, but even more strange are these three:

> 62|error: expected '}' before 'else'|
>
> 70|error: 'else' without a previous 'if'|
>
> 76|error: 'else' without a previous 'if'|

I know what those mean but there is clearly a } before else. and there are if statements before the else

Here is the code:

```
/*
Plants vs Zombies Game of the year edition trainer
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

DWORD FindDmaAddy(int PointerLevel, HANDLE hProcHandle, DWORD Offsets[],DWORD BaseAddress); 
void WriteToMemory(HANDLE hProcHandle);

std::string GameName = "PlantsVsZombies";
LPCSTR LGameWindow = "Plants vs. Zombies";
std::string GameStatus;

bool IsGameAvail;
bool UpdateOnNextRun;

//Zon var.
bool SunStatus;
BYTE SunValue[] = {0xA3, 0X1C, 0X0, 0X0};
DWORD SunBaseAddress = {0x025A9E00};
DWORD SunOffsets[] = {0x5560, 0x768, 0x0};

//Geld var.
bool MoneyStatus;
BYTE MoneyValue[] = {0xA3, 0X1C, 0X0, 0X0};
DWORD MoneyBaseAddress = {0x02589E00};
DWORD MoneyOffsets[] = {0x28, 0x82C, 0x0};

int main()
{
HWND hGameWindow = NULL;
int timeSinceLastUpdate = clock();
int GameAvailTMR = clock();
int OnePressTMR = clock();
DWORD dwProcID = NULL;
HANDLE hProcHandle = NULL;
UpdateOnNextRun = true;
std::string sSunStatus = "UIT";
std::string sMoneyStatus = "UIT";

    while(!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD0));
    {
        if(clock() - GameAvailTMR > 100);
        {
            GameAvailTMR = clock();
            IsGameAvail = false;

            hGameWindow = FindWindow(NULL, LGameWindow);
            if(hGameWindow)
            {
                GetWindowThreadProcessId( hGameWindow, dwProcID);
                if(dwProcID != 0)
                {
                    hProcHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwProcID);
                    if(hProcHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || hProcHandle == NULL);
                    {
                        GameStatus = "Plants vs. Zombies.exe kon niet worden geopend";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       GameStatus = "Plants vs. Zombies.exe is geopend en klaar om gehackt te worden";
                       IsGameAvail = true;
                       system("color 0A");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                {
                    GameStatus = "Kon het process ID niet vinden";
                    system("color 0C");
                }
        }
        else
        {
            GameStatus = "Plants vs. Zombies is niet gevonden";
            system("color 0C");
        }

        if(UpdateOnNextRun || clock() - timeSinceLastUpdate > 5000)
        {
            system("cls");
            std::cout << "---------------------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "                        Plants vs Zombies Trainer" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "---------------------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Game Status: " << GameStatus << std::endl << std::endl;
            std::cout <<"[NUMPAD1] Oneindig Zon: " << sSunStatus << std::endl;
            std::cout <<"[NUMPAD2] Oneindig Geld: " << sMoneyStatus << std::endl;
            std::cout <<"[NUMPAD0] Sluit de trainer";
        }
        if(IsGameAvail)
        {
            if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD1))
            {
                OnePressTMR = clock();
                SunStatus = !SunStatus;
                UpdateOnNextRun = true;
                if(SunStatus)sSunStatus = "ON";
                else sSunStatus = "OFF";
            }
            else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD2))
            {
                OnePressTMR = clock();
                MoneyStatus = !MoneyStatus;
                UpdateOnNextRun = true;
                if(MoneyStatus)sMoneyStatus = "ON";
                else sMoneyStatus = "OFF";
        }
    }
    if(clock() - OnePressTMR > 400)
    {
        if(IsGameAvail)
        {
            //Zon
            if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD1))
            {
                OnePressTMR = clock ();
                SunStatus = !SunStatus;
                UpdateOnNextRun = true;
                if(SunStatus)sSunStatus = "AAN";
                else sSunStatus = "UIT";
            }
            //Geld
            else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD2))
            {
                OnePressTMR = clock ();
                MoneyStatus = !MoneyStatus;
                UpdateOnNextRun = true;
                if(MoneyStatus)sMoneyStatus = "AAN";
                else sMoneyStatus = "UIT";
            }
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hProcHandle);
    CloseHandle(hGameWindow);

    return ERROR_SUCCESS;


}

DWORD FindDmaAddy(int PointerLevel, HANDLE hProcHandle, DWORD Offsets[], DWORD BaseAddress)
{
    DWORD pointer = BaseAddress;
    DWORD pTemp;

DWORD pointerAddr;
for(int i = 0; i <PointerLevel; i++)
{
    if(i == 0)
    {
        ReadProcessMemory(hProcHandle, (LPCVOID)pointer, &pTemp, sizeof(pTemp), NULL);
    }

    pointerAddr = pTemp + Offsets[i];
    ReadProcessMemory(hProcHandle, (LPCVOID)pointerAddr, &pTemp, sizeof(pTemp), NULL);

}
}

void WriteToMemory(HANDLE hProcHandle)
{
    DWORD AddressToWrite;
    if(SunStatus)
{
    AddressToWrite = FindDmaAddy(2, hProcHandle, SunOffsets, SunBaseAddress);
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcHandle,(BYTE*)AddressToWrite, &SunValue, sizeof(SunValue), NULL);
}

if(MoneyStatus)
{
    AddressToWrite = FindDmaAddy(2, hProcHandle, MoneyOffsets, MoneyBaseAddress);
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcHandle,(BYTE*)AddressToWrite, &MoneyValue, sizeof(MoneyValue), NULL);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are sure what you are doing, write something like `DWORD* SunBaseAddress = {0x025A9E00};`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is generally right in its messages, and you should also read its warnings. You code is actually full of silly little mistakes.

```
    if(clock() - GameAvailTMR > 100);
```

the ending `;` closes the `if` here so the else will not be attached to it

```
GetWindowThreadProcessId( hGameWindow, dwProcID);
```

dwProcID is a DWORD when the function signature needs a LPDWORD, that is a DWORD *. Just write `GetWindowThreadProcessId( hGameWindow, &dwProcID);`

Don't forget, when you see an error on one line, also read the above one. Just fix all the errors **and warning** and come back here if you still have problems

Comment: thanks, sorry for the little mistakes i am still a begginer, but I still have some issues i changed what you said to change:                                                                                                                                                                                         38|warning: converting to non-pointer type 'DWORD {aka long unsigned int}' from NULL [-Wconversion-null]|                               145|error: a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token